# Get width Access 2007 navigation pane

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

On startup I want to check whether the navigation pane (left side of the screen) is open so I can minimize it by simulating a keypress. I managed to do it for the ribbon (top of the screen) by using the method `CommandBars("Ribbon").Height`.

I want to do the same thing for the navigation pane. There is a `CommandBars(index).Width` method so I think it should be possible.

I tried getting all the names of all the controlbars but I can't manage to find the correct one. I also tried to compare the width of all controlsbars which name contain "nav" using this code

```
For Each cb In CommandBars
    If (InStr(cb.Name, "nav")) Then
        Debug.Print cb.Name & vbTab & cb.Width
    End If
Next cb
```

I ran this code with both the pane opened and closed but I havent been able to find any differences in width.

Does anyone know how I get the correct width of the navigation pane in Access 2007?

Comment: Would you prefer to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

There's this option: `SendKeys ("{F11}")`. The only catch is knowing if it's already open or not.

This works for some, not others (works on my machine...access 2016):

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.Minimize
```

There's more discussion here: [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0a34dbec-5078-4e16-b6a7-78f62c39f1bf/vba-navigation-pane?forum=accessdev)